# Position: inherit with overlap possible?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make two squares overlap eachother in a parent div. The squares are using position:inherit. Please note that the number of squares will be dynamic. Also note that the parent div is using margin-left: 30%. Is this possible?

```
<div style="border: 1px solid Black; width: 300px; height:300px; margin-left:30%;">
    <div style="height:40px; width:40px; border: 1px solid Black; position:inherit; left:0px; top: 0px;"></div>
    <div style="height:40px; width:40px; border: 1px solid Black; position:inherit; left:0px; top: 0px;"></div>
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AzYUn/1/

Comment: Why would you want to do `position: inherit`? What are they inheriting anyway since you didn't even set any `position` on the parent?

Comment: exactly what u want ? specify it clearly

Comment: I'm creating a scrum wall. The positions of the two "squares" are retrieved from a database and the parent div is the wall. I figured I needed to use position inherit since the parent div is not absolutely positioned (the wall will be centered in the browser).

Comment: That's not going to change anything - since the parent is using the default then the children will use defaults too, which already happens without `position: inherit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `position: inherit;` and use `position: relative;`.

Using the `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties you can move an element and making it overlap.

**CSS**

```css
div.parent {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 30%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

div.parent > div.box {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div.parent > div.box.overlap {
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box overlap"></div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's going to put some strain on my solution, but I'm starting to think (as in your answer) that minus positioning is the only answer.

Comment: @Skalis Even though it feels wrong, that is how CSS works. You just have to accept and get over it - I know exactly how it feels. /hug/

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to use other position value - relative or even absolute to reach that goal.